# Objective C: 18 is not greater than -1?

Tags: objective-c

I have a very peculiar problem here. I'm building a spider to grab hyperlinks from a webpage and put them into a table and I'm using `NSRanges` to parse the HTML document, but I've run into an issue.

I have the following line of code:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", [dataString rangeOfString:@"contents.asp?year1" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(index, dataString.length - index)].length);
```

This echoes `18` to the log, as it should, but if I put that into a boolean statement, seeing if that length is greater than -1:

```
NSLog(@"%d", ([dataString rangeOfString:@"contents.asp?year1" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(index, dataString.length - index)].length > -1));
```

This echoes 0, or false. 18 is clearly greater than -1, so what's the problem? If I switch it to `< -1`, it returns true. Does this have something to do with type-casting the unsigned long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [the definition of `NSRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW23):

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
      NSUInteger location;
      NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

Notice that both fields are of type `NSUInteger`, an unsigned type.  In fact, `NSUInteger` is `unsigned long`.

Since there is no wider integer type than `unsigned long`, the compiler promotes `-1` to unsigned.  I can't recall whether this is undefined behavior, but on iOS and Mac OS X it has the effect of treating the 2's complement bit pattern of -1 as an unsigned integer.  That bit pattern, as an unsigned integer, is the maximum unsigned integer value.

Thus your comparison can never be true.

If you think `-1` means "not found", you are mistaken.  The correct way to check whether `rangeOfString:options:range:` failed to find the target is to check whether the `location` of the returned range is [`NSNotFound`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW3):

```
NSUInteger location = [dataString rangeOfString:@"contents.asp?year1"
    options:0 range:NSMakeRange(index, dataString.length - index)].location
BOOL foundIt = location != NSNotFound;
```

Comment: Ah okay. See there I was thinking all languages were the same again. Silly me. :)

Comment: It's also worth noting, based on the OP: Don't check whether the location is *greater than* NSNotFound — just check for inequality.